# How to get value from array of nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data like this from http:

```js
[{
  "mode": "CURR",
  "isin": "PLESLTN00010",
  "from": 451183,
  "to": null,
  "data": [{
    "t": 1624265539,
    "p": 5,
    "o": 5,
    "c": 5,
    "l": 5,
    "h": 5,
    "v": 2
  }]
}]
```

and how to get value of "data" for "c" ?

Trying this:

```js
const arrNcnct = ncdata.map(a => a.data).flat();
```

it's ok. get

```js
[{ "t": 1624265539, "p": 5, "o": 5, "c": 5, "l": 5, "h": 5, "v": 2 }]
```

but couldn't to get value of "c"

```js
const c = arrNcnct.map(el => ({ current: el.c}));
console.log(Object.values(c));
```

return

```js
[{"current": 5}]
```

I have missed something...

Comment: c is an array you are using Object properties.

Comment: You could just use the array indexes? `arr[0].data[0].c`

Comment: ```const output = ncdata.map(a => a.data[0].c);``` should do the trick.

Comment: `arrNcnct.map(el => el.c)` ?

Comment: adiga -> no,  arrNcnct.map(el => el.c); is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what could be done:

```
let response = [{
  "mode":"CURR", "isin":"PLESLTN00010", "from":451183, "to":null,
  "data":[{"t":1624265539, "p":5, "o":5, "c":5, "l":5, "h":5, "v":2}]
}];
        
let innerResponse = response[0].data;
```

`innerResponse` is an array. If you have only one element in the array, you can access it by using `innerResponse[0]`, but if you have more than one element, then you need to use a loop.

If you want to access the "c" property, do `innerResponse[0].c`

Comment: Yes it helps ;)

Comment: @Bear4 Great! Kindly upvote the answer if you can. :)